# Advanced window configuration: order + group + length_batch

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I need some help to create a window to manage events with the folowing rules:

- Get events ordered by timestamp (arrival can be unordered)
- Group these events by a key (`customerId`)
- Finally do a `length_batch` per 2 events to create an edge from one event to another.

My problem is: what could be the good way to do that ?

---

I tried to create a window with `groupwin(customerId).length_batch(2)` but I failed to find a way to add the first rule: order

My EPL queries:

```
create window winEdge.std:groupwin(customerId).win:length_batch(2) as select customerId,type,ts from Stream

insert into winEdge customerId,type,ts from Stream

select customerId, 'edge' as type, concatstr(type) as path, count(type) as nb_events, sum(ts) as total_time, (last(ts)-first(ts)) as elapsed, first(ts) as fromTs, last(ts) as toTs from winEdge group by customerId
```

I tried to add an `order by` condition or to use the `ex:time_order()` but no success.

Is there someone to help/explain me what could be the good way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time-order view orders unordered events. See http://espertech.com/esper/release-5.3.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#view-time-order

Two EPL statements, the first one produces a stream for the second one to consume:

```
// produce ordered stream
insert rstream into ArrivalTimeOrderedStream
select rstream * from MyTimestampedEvent.ext:time_order(arrival_time, 10 sec);

// aggregate
select first(xxx), last(xxx), ... from ArrivalTimeOrderedStream
.groupwin(customerId).length_batch(2) group by customerid
```

Comment: Thanks it works. The groups are correctly based on customerId but the groups generated by the aggregate query are not ordrered by time. I tried to add an "order by" to the query but no success.

Comment: When saying "the groups generated by the aggregate query are not ordrered by time" then I may ask what time? The time that the first datapoint for a given group arrived for a given batch or the first-ever timestamp for a given group or the last or...? I sounds like the order-by clause could simply order by say "firstever(timestamp)"

Comment: And is it event time or perhaps the system time when the reordered output was generated - there are so many unlisted requirements questions

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. Order by first(ts) for example.